# querying relation does not give back related object in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a very simple table(mapped as AuthToken class), consisting of a string ('token'), and a userid (foreign key to another table), with 'user' as relation ( = class User)

session.query(AuthToken.user).one() gives back the token, and the userid (as a tuple), but not the user object.

Does anybody know why?

thanks!

Comment: Did you ever come to a solution for this problem?

Comment: Not exactly - as Daniel has written, we should query objects, not their attributes, however since then I've seen querying attributes in sqlalchemy docs as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should query mapped classes, not their attributes, if you want to receive objects.

```
token = Session.query(AuthToken).options(eagerload('user')).filter(...).one()
user = token.user
```

Comment: You're right, I can query only classes, this answers my question. Altough the reason I was trying to do this as I did not want to query every attribute of "AuthToken", only 'user', I thought this is the way to do it.

Comment: @sobear, thats possible, you just have to query it from User class instead of AuthToken, like `user = Session.query(User).join(AuthToken).filter(AuthToken.... == ...).one()`, this way it will pull only user object.